# docker fails with on MacOs Sierra with 'MSpanList_Insert 0x8f1000 0x81d2db0339 0x0'

Tags: docker, macos-sierra

While running

```
docker -v
```

on MacOs Sierra 10.13.3 following error is printed and docker exists

```
failed MSpanList_Insert 0x8f1000 0x81d2db0339 0x0
fatal error: MSpanList_Insert

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x80d7ab)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:491 +0xad fp=0x7ffeefbfef10 sp=0x7ffeefbfeee0
runtime.MSpanList_Insert(0x846e88, 0x8f1000)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:692 +0x8f fp=0x7ffeefbfef38 sp=0x7ffeefbfef10
MHeap_FreeSpanLocked(0x843a80, 0x8f1000, 0x100)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:583 +0x163 fp=0x7ffeefbfef78 sp=0x7ffeefbfef38
MHeap_Grow(0x843a80, 0x8, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:420 +0x1a8 fp=0x7ffeefbfefb8 sp=0x7ffeefbfef78
.....
```

I've re-installed docker from docker.com and reboot the system several times. The problem does not go away

Comment: this error may be related to `kubectl`, I'm currently seeing this error for that command, they are related projects docker and kubernetes. I don't get your error however for `docker -v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely caused by older versions of `go` running on osx.
For me I removed older versions of go I had installed via brew, you can see all go's on your system by doing

```
which -a go
```

make sure you only have one and it's a recent version.

Next you should reinstall the tool to make sure you have a version of it compiled on a recent version of go.

This would probably be docker CE for osx https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac

My issue was with `kubectl` so I did `gcloud components install kubectl` instead.