# 'docker -v' fails on MacOs Mojave with 'MSpanList_Insert 0x743000 0x1d03f7990b2f 0x0'

Tags: docker, macos-mojave

I am trying to get Docker Desktop for Mac up and running on my Mac under MacOs Mojave 10.14.5. After install, upon running

```
docker -v
```

I receive the following error:

```
failed MSpanList_Insert 0x743000 0x1d03f7990b2f 0x0
fatal error: MSpanList_Insert
```

I have tried:

1. Rebooting the system.
2. Uninstalling and reinstalling `docker` and rebooting.
3. Checking to see if I have `go` installed (I did not). See this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950249/docker-fails-with-on-macos-sierra-with-mspanlist-insert-0x8f1000-0x81d2db0339-0)
4. Installing `go` (go1.12.6 darwin/amd64) using `brew`.
5. Uninstalling and reinstalling `go`.

More detail from the error is below:
    failed MSpanList_Insert 0x743000 0x1d03f7990b2f 0x0
    fatal error: MSpanList_Insert

```
runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x69460b)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:491 +0xad fp=0x7ffeefbff240 sp=0x7ffeefbff210
runtime.MSpanList_Insert(0x6bd368, 0x743000)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:692 +0x8f fp=0x7ffeefbff268 sp=0x7ffeefbff240
MHeap_FreeSpanLocked(0x6b9f60, 0x743000, 0x100)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:583 +0x163 fp=0x7ffeefbff2a8 sp=0x7ffeefbff268
MHeap_Grow(0x6b9f60, 0x8, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:420 +0x1a8 fp=0x7ffeefbff2e8 sp=0x7ffeefbff2a8
MHeap_AllocSpanLocked(0x6b9f60, 0x1, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:298 +0x365 fp=0x7ffeefbff328 sp=0x7ffeefbff2e8
mheap_alloc(0x6b9f60, 0x1, 0x12, 0x0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:190 +0x121 fp=0x7ffeefbff350 sp=0x7ffeefbff328
```

....

Comment: Hope this helps. https://github.com/github/hub/issues/1405

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Unfortunately, it didn't seem to apply. I'm not using macports, and I didn't have `hub` on the system, but I did install it and reinstalled `git`. I also uninstalled and reinstalled `go` one more time, and ran 'brew list --versions go' just to be sure there was only one version of `go` installed, and there is only one (go 1.12.16). Still getting the same error.